# Browser Push Notification implementation in SharePoint 2013 web application

Tags: sharepoint-server, notifications

I am trying to implement browser push notification for Chrome in SharePoint 2013.

I had added web manifest file in Site Assets and referred that in Master Page as below:

```
"`<link rel="manifest" href="../../SiteAssets/Data/manifest.json" />`"
```

But it is giving me "401 Unauthorized" Error when page is loaded.

Can somebody guide me how to proceed with Browser push notification implementation in SharePoint 2013?

(I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/getting-started/push-notifications/?hl=en) article from Google.)